# Scala case class: how to set computed value for a member

Tags: scala

I want to generate a random number to store in the "id" member of case class and be used a primary key when stored in the DB. If passed a non-zero value of id, then that value should be used, not generate new one.

```
case class User(name: String, id: Long = 0L)
```

I tried

```
object User {
  def apply(name: String, id: Long): User = 
    User(name, (id == 0L) ? <some random number> : id)
}
```

But get some error like:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition
...
method apply is defined twice
```

I don't want to introduce another member in the case class.

Comment: which scala version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message stats you are overriding your apply method. You should use `new`in the `apply` definition.

```
object User {
  def apply(name: String, id: Long): User = 
   new User(name, if(id == 0L)  <some random number> else id)
}
```

Comment: This does not compile for me (in 2.11.11), and I don't think it should: you are still defining `apply` twice.

Comment: @Dima it compiles in 2.12.x. Proof: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stsatlantis/ZZZnfuwGSDKQcnFGjLUWrg . However you are right it doesn't compile in 2.11.x

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` ternary operator is not supported here. The error `apply method defined twice` as it was defined as `case class`.But it is compiled successfully in scala 2.12.6 even for the definition of `case class`. I changed to this and it compiles:

```
  class User(name: String, id: Long = 0L)
  object User {
  def apply(name: String, id: Long): User =
   new User(name,if(id == 0L) scala.util.Random.nextLong else id)
  }
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class User(name: String, id: Long = 0L)
object User {
  def apply(name: String, id: Long): User =
   new User(name,if(id == 0L) scala.util.Random.nextLong else id)}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class User
defined object User

scala>
```

Comment: This does not compile for me (in 2.11.11), and I don't think it should: you are still defining apply twice.

Comment: What the poster is actually missing appears to be the `new` keyword. Ternary operators are indeed no longer supported but I think the "ambiguous reference" error is better solved with @stsatlantis's answer.

Comment: It compiled in `Scala 2.12.6` REPL in ` :paste` mode.

Answer (score 1):

As, others pointed out scala uses `if ... else` instead of java's `? .. : ..` (you'd get this error next, after your "apply is defined twice" problem was resolved).

The immediate problem is that case classes have a default `apply` method generated for them, with the parameters of the case class, so the one you are defining is a duplicate.

You can get around it by stripping the default from the the constructor, and removing the second parameter from the apply:

```
   case class User(name: String, id: Long)
   object User { def apply(name: String) = User(name, Random.nextLong) }
```

This will compile, and is also better because you don't need to treat 0 as a sentinel value anymore. When you do `User(name, 1)`, the default apply is called, and you get the instance with a given id, when you do `User(name)`, that invokes your custom `apply`, and you get a random id,

I assume, you know that in this simple case, you could just do

```
case class User(name: String, id: Long = Random.nextLong)
```

, right? This approach (with overloading apply) is more useful in situations, when the default value for one (or more) of the parameters depends on the values of others, so that you can't just write the default in parameter list, e.g.:

```
case class Parent(child: Person, lastName: String)
object Parent { 
   def apply(child: Person) = Parent(child, child.lastName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach is like this

```
case class User(name: String, private val _id: Long = 0L) {
  lazy val id: Long = if(_id == 0) Random.nextLong() else _id
}
```

**EDIT:** Note that this approach has the downside of breaking the equals contract on the case class: 2 instances of User where you pass an `_id = 0` will have different ids, but will be equal since the case class equals method only looks at the constructor params

Comment: This is not a good idea. It largely defeats the purpose of it being a case class, and makes the behavior rather weird.  Try `User("foo") == User("foo")` for example, and compare it to `User("foo").id == User("foo").id`. Also deconstruction -  things like `User("foo") match { case User(_, id) => id }` - won't even compile.

Comment: Oh, true. Nice point. Will edit my answer to reflect that. Thanks!